# pysparkDistributedKmodes lib error

Tags: python-2.7, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to run pyspark-distributed-kmodes example:

```
import numpy as np
data = np.random.choice(["a", "b", "c"], (50000, 10))
data2 = np.random.choice(["e", "f", "g"], (50000, 10))
data = list(data) + list(data2)

from random import shuffle
shuffle(data)

# Create a Spark RDD from our sample data and decrease partitions to max_partions
max_partitions = 32

rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
rdd = rdd.coalesce(max_partitions)

for x in rdd.take(10):
    print x

method = EnsembleKModes(n_clusters, max_iter)
model = method.fit(df.rdd)

print(model.clusters)
print(method.mean_cost)

predictions = method.predictions
datapoints = method.indexed_rdd
combined = datapoints.zip(predictions)
print(combined.take(10))

model.predict(rdd).take(5)
```

I'm using Python 2.7, Apache Zeppelin 0.7.1 and Apache Spark 2.1.0.

This is the output error:

```
('Iteration ', 0)

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1298251609305129154.py", line 349, in <module>
        raise Exception(traceback.format_exc())
    Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/tmp/zeppelin_pyspark-1298251609305129154.py", line 337, in <module>
        exec(code)
      File "<stdin>", line 13, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark_kmodes/pyspark_kmodes.py", line 430, in fit
        self.n_clusters,self.max_dist_iter)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark_kmodes/pyspark_kmodes.py", line 271, in k_modes_partitioned
        clusters = check_for_empty_cluster(clusters, rdd)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspark_kmodes/pyspark_kmodes.py", line 317, in check_for_empty_cluster
        random_element = random.choice(clusters[biggest_cluster].members)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/random.py", line 275, in choice
        return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
    IndexError: list index out of range
```

the RDD used to fit the model is not empty, i've checked it. I think that is a   versions incompatibility problem between pyspark-distributed-kmodes and spark, but I can't downgrade Spark.

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is `df`? Doesn't look like a spark error. The code from https://github.com/ThinkBigAnalytics/pyspark-distributed-kmodes is working for me under Spark 2.1.0. Even when I changed this line of code from yours it also works:

```
method = EnsembleKModes(n_clusters, max_iter)
model = method.fit(rdd)
```

Comment: You are rigth, df is a mistake. Now it works fine. Thanks